# Js event inside an other js event mobile device

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm wondering how to handle an event inside an other one

Here is the code I use:

```js
var title=document.getElementsByClassName('lv1');
for (var i = 0; i < title.length; i++) {
      title[i].addEventListener('click',  (event) => {
      alert("click title");
},false);
}
var deleted=document.getElementsByClassName('remove');
for (var i = 0; i < deleted.length; i++) {
  deleted[i].addEventListener('click',  (event) => {
    alert("click remove");
  },false);
}
```

```html
<div class="lv1">
  <h1>
    test
  </h1>
  <button class="remove">
  REMOVE
  </button>
</div>
```

You have two click events `lv1` and `delete`. But `delete` is inside `lv1`, so when I go for `delete`, both click events are triggered.

On computer, I can fix this by adding a `mouseover` event to know if I'm hovering the delete or not and this way I know if the `lv1` event must be triggered or not.

But I can't use this trick with mobile device; the `mouseover` event didn't exist.
Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

```js
var title=document.getElementsByClassName('lv1');
for (var i = 0; i < title.length; i++) {
      title[i].addEventListener('click',  (event) => {
      alert("click title");
},false);
}
var deleted=document.getElementsByClassName('remove');
for (var i = 0; i < deleted.length; i++) {
  deleted[i].addEventListener('click',  (event) => {
    alert("click remove");
    event.stopPropagation();
  },false);
}
```

```html
<div class="lv1">
  <h1>
    test
  </h1>
  <button class="remove">
  REMOVE
  </button>
</div>
```